# backward one Step/Dir in Gitbash

Tags: git-bash

I am using GitBash `-Which` command is used to go up one directory (e.g `C:\Users\Public\Spider` to `C:\Users\Public`). While `cd..` and `cd ~` are Redirecting to `C:` and `cd/` is not working " Is there any command that would work?

Thank You...

Answer (score 1):

Use `cd ..` (notice the space) in the git bash command prompt.